# Execute stored procedure with a nullable parameter from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, MYTASK1, with several parameters. It gets called something like this:

```
EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021' , '1','1'
```

How do I run the stored procedure if the parameter is null. I tried

```
EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021' , '' ,''
```

but it doesn't do anything.

my stored procedure

```sql
ALTER PROC MYTASK1 @Year varchar(6) = NULL,
                   @quarter varchar(6) = NULL,
                   @month varchar(6) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Sell Out' AS name,
           'Total Sales Amount' AS Description,
           'down' AS status,
           CAST(SUM(NetValue) AS decimal(9, 2)) AS amount
    FROM SalesAndReturns_RPT
    GROUP BY YEAR(Call_ActualStartDate),
             DATEPART(QUARTER, Call_ActualStartDate),
             MONTH(Call_ActualStartDate)
    HAVING YEAR(Call_ActualStartDate) = @Year
       AND DATEPART(QUARTER, Call_ActualStartDate) = @quarter
       AND MONTH(Call_ActualStartDate) = @month;

END;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to filter rows in your query only when the quarter/month is supplied...? Also FYI the date functions you use all return integer values, your parameters should also be integers.

Comment: Why are your clauses in the `HAVING` where there is no aggregation? Those should be in the `WHERE`.

Comment: without group by??? @Larnu

Comment: `YEAR(Call_ActualStartDate) = @Year` `YEAR` isn't an aggregate function, @Rat , so why is that clause in the `HAVING` and not the `WHERE`?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here anyway. YOu `GROUP BY` certain values, but then filter on them in the `HAVING`. There's no need for that `GRUUP BY` and those clauses should be in the `WHERE` *not* the `HAVING`.

Comment: I want  display the total net value for the selected months ,Quarter or Year @Larnu

Comment: So, again, why not filter in the `WHERE`...? Why do you have a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`?

Comment: If you provide a value of `@Month` (let's say `4`) but not `@Year` or `@Quarter` do you want a value for every one of those months (April in this case) regardless of year? What happens if you provide `4` for `@Month` and `3` for `@Quarter`?

Comment: EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021' , NULL ,NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, but I assume this is what you want:

```sql
ALTER PROC dbo.MYTASK1 @Year int = NULL, --Makes no sense as a varchar(6)
                       @Quarter int = NULL, --Makes no sense as a varchar(6)
                       @Month int = NULL --Makes no sense as a varchar(6)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 'Sell Out' AS name,
           'Total Sales Amount' AS Description,
           'down' AS status,
           CAST(SUM(NetValue) AS decimal(9, 2)) AS amount
    FROM dbo.SalesAndReturns_RPT
    WHERE ((Call_ActualStartDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 1) AND Call_ActualStartDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@Year+1, 1, 1)) OR @Year IS NULL)
      AND (DATEPART(QUARTER, Call_ActualStartDate) = @Quarter OR @Quarter IS NULL)
      AND (DATEPART(MONTH,Call_ActualStartDate) = @Month OR @Month IS NULL)
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);

END;
```

I have made the clause for `@Year` SARGable, however, with no information about on how `@month` and `@quarter` should be handled if `@Year` is `NULL` then this will likely make little difference, as those clauses are not SARGable. I have *assumed* that if `@Year` is `NULL` but `@Month` isn't, you would want the `SUM` for all rows in that month, regardless of the year it falls in.

If you do want a SARGable solution for this requirement, you'll need to implement a Calendar table.

Answer (score 1):

The code which you are executing: `EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021' , '' ,''` triggers procedure `MYTASK1` with empty strings as parameters. Please note that empty string is it a different value than null... NULL is lacks of value, while empty string is totally valid string ;)

You can try
`EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021' , NULL ,NULL`

In your case NULL is a defoult value, so you can also use:
`EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021'`

Comment: not working @Radek

Answer (score 1):

Since you have NULL as default, you can just not provide a parameter value at all

```
EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021'
```

is the same as

```
EXECUTE MYTASK1 '2021', NULL, NULL
```

You can also use named parameters like so:

```
EXECUTE MYTASK1 @quarter='Q1'
```

However, going by other answers and comments, you have substantial issues with the contect of the stored proc.